# Intensity of waves in single-slit diffraction

Tags: optics, diffraction

So I am trying to determine the relation between intensities of waves in single slit diffraction. Since I am pretty new to this topic, I couldn't find a way how to calculate the ratio between the intensities of the source wave and central maxima. I have found how to calculate the ratio between the intensity of the central maxima and surrounding maxima. However, I see there is no source that can help me to determine the relation between the intensity of the source wave and central maxima.

Thus, let's say we have a plate with a single slit whose width is $\lambda_1$ $  \mu m $ and we send a light beam with wavelength $\lambda_2$ $  \mu m $ towards this plate from a source which is $x_1$ $m$ away from the plate. Moreover, we have a screen which is $x_2$ $m$ away from the plate. If we say that the intensity of the source wave is $I$, then what would be the intensity of the central maxima in terms of $I$? I also think this can be answered by calculating the total energies of waves but since it is an electromagnetic wave, I think the calculations may get harder.

P.S: The source is point-like and the slit is circular so we expect an airy disk pattern.

Comment: You can look this up easily enough at, e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffraction#Single-slit_diffraction

Comment: @FarStar you give too few details about the configuration of your problem. Is your source point-like? Then the intensity of the wave decreases with the distance $r$ from the source as $1/(4pi r^2)$. Is the slit circular or a long slit of the mentioned width?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft I believe that equation gives the relation between the intensities of central maxima and other maximas not the intensities of central maxima and source.

Comment: @Sofia Yes the source is point-like and the slit is circular so we expect an airy disk pattern on the screen.

Comment: @FarStar Intensity of light from the source at the slit opening?

Comment: @user35122 No, intensity of the light when it is initially emitted from the source.

Comment: @FarStar I don't get what you mean by intensity of light initially emitted from the source. Without specifying the  area (maybe an infinitesimal one too) over which power is incident you cannot specify intensity. Though total power radiated by the source makes sense.